# how to create a timer minutes by pressing the button?

Tags: java, android, button

how to create a timer for 2 minutes by pressing the button?
I want to create a button that after pressing this button will unclicable for 2 minutes

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. You need to provide some code so we can see what you have done so far and we will be able to help. Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this --

use Handler(import android.os.Handler;)

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn.setEnabled(false);

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                btn.setEnabled(true);
                Log.d(TAG,"resend1");

        }
    },120000);// set time as per your requirement 
    }
});
```

Comment: 20000 millisecond is how much? Is it 1/3 minutes?

Comment: 10 Second means - 10000